# Is it possible to make command bar fixed ?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm currently learning XAML and C# and i'd like to know is it possible to make Command Bar fixed (for example when i press three dots everything else should be fixed ) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some code that you tried already and it didn't work. Also please refer to "How to ask" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask article to help you structure your question, so it can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the UI tool in Visual Studio you should not be worried about fixing the position of the elements in your UI as you place elements on a grid.

When you click on the three dots of the CommandBar the element will be hovering natively the content placed near it.
For more information, you may watch the MSDN description : [MSDN CommandBar class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx)

As you are learning XAML/C# and UWP, you should have a look to the samples proposed by Microsoft on their GitHub : [Github - Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples)

Comment: I'll check them out , i'll also try to port some open source iOS apps to master C# and XAML.

Comment: Another useful information as you want to port some iOS apps to Windows application, you should have a look to the new Windows Tool that will easily help you : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/ios

Comment: Thanks, i'll look at it.